# Get only attributes if another attribute has specific value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Ok, first question on stackoverflow.

I have the following xml:

```
<movies>
  <movie>
    <cast>
      <person name="Tim Johnson" character="" job="Director"/> 
      <person name="Avril Lavigne" character="Heather (voice)" job="Actor"/> 
      <person name="Omid Djalili" character="Tiger (voice)" job="Actor"/>
      <person name="Karey Kirkpatrick" character="" job="Director"/>
    </cast>
  </movie>
</movies>
```

I retrieve it like this:

```
<?php $xml_getinfo_result = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($tmdb_getinfo_result)); ?>
```

To get the cast, I use the following:

```
$i = 0;
while ($xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person[$i]) {
  $tmdb_actors = $xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person[$i]->attributes()->name;
  echo "<li>".$tmdb_actors."</li>";
$i++;
}
```

This gives me:

```
<li>Tim Johnson</li>
<li>Avril Lavigne</li>
<li>Omid Djalili</li>
<li>Karey Kirkpatrick</li>
```

But what do I need to do if I want to display only the persons whose job is "Actor"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get an xml object by attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542171/get-an-xml-object-by-attribute)

Comment: Gordon: Sorry, didn't see that one in my search before posting this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person[$i]) {
  $tmdb_job = $xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person[$i]->attributes()->job;
  if($tmdb_job == 'Actor'){
     $tmdb_name = $xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person[$i]->attributes()->name;
     echo "<li>".$tmdb_name."</li>";
  }
$i++;
}
```

Comment: This is nice too, this way I can specify different jobs and output them accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

The first one, you get all data and you display only actor:

```
$i = 0;
while ($xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person[$i]) {
  if ($xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person[$i]->attributes()->job == "Actor") {
     $tmdb_actors = $xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person[$i]->attributes()->name;
     echo "<li>".$tmdb_actors."</li>";
  }
$i++;
}
```

The second one is to parse only `<person>` that are actor and display all result.

Comment: change `attributes()->name` to `attributes()->job` in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
while ($xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person[$i]) {
  $job = $xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person[$i]->attributes()->job;
  if ($job == 'Actor') {
    $tmdb_actors = $xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person[$i]->attributes()->name;
    echo "<li>".$tmdb_actors."</li>";
    }
  $i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$actorNodes = $xml_getinfo_result->xpath( '//person[@job="Actor"]' );
foreach( $actorNodes as $actorNode )
{
    echo "<li>".$actorNode->attributes()->name."</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd throw it in a foreach statement

```
foreach ($xml_getinfo_result->movies->movie->cast->person as $id => $person) {
    if ($person->attributes()->job === 'Actor') {
        echo '<li>' . $person->attributes()->name . '</li>';
    }
}
```